# Prezto theme not loading

Tags: zsh, prezto

I have the following line in my `.zpreztorc` file:

```
zstyle ':prezto:module:prompt' theme 'paradox'
```

And when I type `prompt -c` in my terminal it returns:

```
Current prompt theme is:
  paradox
```

But the theme itself is not loaded. Only after I type run `prompt paradox` does the theme actually display. Is there anything else I need to add to any configuration file to make sure the theme actually loads when I start my terminal. I'm using iTerm2 and I already have powerline installed properly.

Answer (score 2):

There have been issues in the past with presto's prompt setting; IMO it is best to add to the theme to your .zshrc:

```
promptinit
prompt paradox
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using prezto add

```
$ echo "prompt paradox" >> ~/.zshrc
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

if you are using yadr

```
$ echo "prompt paradox" >> ~/.zsh.after/prompt.zsh
$ source ~/.zshrc
```